# how to insert null into sql database with ADO.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

i have a DropDownList that display a collection of subset based on SetID from another ddl and some times it is null. how i can insert null value into database ?
i tried with this code but not work:

```
CmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@SubsetID",SqlDbType.Int);
if (ddlSubset.Items.Count!=0)
{
  CmdUpdate.Parameters["@SubsetID"].Value=ddlSubset.SelectedValue;
}
esle
{
  CmdUpdate.Parameters["@SubsetID"].Value=null;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`System.DBNull`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.dbnull.aspx) class:

```
CmdUpdate.Parameters["@SubsetID"].Value = DBNull.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use DBNull:

```
CmdUpdate.Parameters["@SubsetID"].Value = DBNull.Value;
```